# Heredoc on docker exec

Tags: python, bash, shell, docker, heredoc

I'm basically trying to have a heredoc be executed by Flask-migrate's shell with Flask app context

Below is the command i'm trying to run inside my bash script

```
$ docker exec -it mycontainer ./manage shell <<-EOF
    # shell commands to be executed
EOF
```

When trying to execute the above command I get:

`cannot enable tty mode on non tty input`

This is the **manage** file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from middleware import create_app, config
from middleware.models import db

from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand


app = create_app(config)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

My question is there a way to pass set of commands like in heredoc to the shell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove `-t` option from `docker exec` command to remove attached `pseudo-TTY` OR use `--tty=false`:

```
docker exec -i mycontainer ./manage shell <<-EOF
    # shell commands to be executed
EOF
```

Or else:

```
docker exec -i --tty=false mycontainer ./manage shell <<-EOF
    # shell commands to be executed
EOF
```